# Kotlin always tells me KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jar

I've just started converting to Kotlin from Java. I have a question: when I'm reflecting something like: 
`XXClass::class.java`
 
or anything else. They **don't work in JAR**, but work fine from IDE.

I'm using `gradle :module:build` or `gradle :module:jar` to generate the JAR file. After generating, it always tells me `KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath`. But I've already added them into dependencies, and they work fine in IDE.

These are parts of my gradle files (Please notice that this is a kotlin application module, not an Android module):

```
// (Module level)
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
dependencies {
    // Others...
    // I've already added reflect and stdlib
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        // ...
    }

    // To include dependencies to build a fat jar
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { 
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
        }
    }
}

// Include reflect and stdlib
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true
        noReflect = false
        noStdlib = false
    }
}

// (Project level)
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        // ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know what the problem could be, because I tested it and is working for me

Comment: You could try **shadow**, maybe it works better

Comment: @OmarMainegra I'm using Gradle 5.1, which **shadow** doesn't support.

Comment: @OmarMainegra Does it works for you with gradle jar task? Or just works with shadow?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this block of script

```
        configurations.compile.collect { 
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
        }
```

You've included the dependencies ( kotlin-reflect ) using **implementation** configuration, but collecting the dependencies from **compile** configuration. If you changed your config from implementation to compile, this block will work. Since **compile**  is deprecated, you can try something like this to collect your dependencies to your jar

```
        compileJava.classpath.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
```

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899110/7790047)