# Intellij Grade Build Jar with dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar, debian

I want to build a jar file in IntelliJ IDEA with Gradle.
When I run my code in Intellij everything works fine, 
but when I run the jar file I get an error:

```
SQLExecption: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/applications/elite-dangerous/database/ED_Database.db
```

I build the jar throw pressing the build button.

[image]

[image]

It's strange for me because it works perfectly fine when I run it in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Did you try using the [Shadow](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar) plug-in instead? If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies included using **implementation** config are not being included in the Jar which makes them not available in runtime. So, I guess that could be the case. You can try changing **implementation** to **compile** dependencies ( which is deprecated, so not recommended ) or You can include your dependencies in the jar as below

```
 jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'eliteDangerousRestUpdater.Main'
    }
    from {
        compileJava.classpath.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just now revisited this answer after your comment. Sorry, I've missed the intentional answer here. Edited it now. Please check the code now.